# Should protected methods be unit-tested? How to avoid repetitive testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Using C#

I know this has been asked before and a lot of people will answer no, only test public methods, not implementation details. Others will say yes, if it has some important logic. Although you might then consider breaking it off into its own class.

One issue I haven't seen addressed is having to repeat testing public methods that call protected methods in inherited classes.
If I test the protected method in the base class, surely I don't have to retest it in base classes. Or should I copy and paste the tests to multiple classes?

Comment: A (not necessary the best) way is to derive from the class and provide well known behaviour in this class. Everything you test now is then the base class only. Well known behaviour is necessary to avoid testing the test class or the integration of it when deriving from it in real classes.

Comment: I think you would want to duplicate your tests for each derived class.  Imagine that someone changes one derived class to no longer use the protected method.  If you don't explicitly test each derived class, even if they have the same behavior, you won't notice that type of change happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely should test protected methods. From a testing standpoint, a "protected" method still is part of the public interface, even though the "public" is limited to those classes that derive from your class. Because code that you do not control can reference those methods, you must ensure that they function as defined.

As for repetitive testing, I don't have a definitive answer. If given:

```
public class A
{
    protected virtual void Foo() {}
}

public class B:A
{

}
```

The question is whether you write a test for `B.Foo`. On one hand I would say no, because `B` doesn't provide an explicit implementation of `Foo`, and so its behavior can't possibly be different than the behavior of `A.Foo`, and we can assume that you've already tested `A.Foo`.

On the other hand, `A.Foo` could depend on some other `protected` fields or properties that `B` could modify, or on a private callback that `B` provides in a constructor or initialization function. In that case, then you absolutely must test `B.Foo` because its behavior *could* be different than `A.Foo`, even though `B` doesn't override `A.Foo`.

Obviously, if `B` overrides `Foo`, then you have to write a test for `B.Foo`. But if `B` doesn't override `A.Foo`, then you have to use your judgement.

All that said, it's really no different from having to write tests for any class that derives from another. Consider deriving a class from [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx). Would you write explicit unit tests for all of the virtual functions defined by the `TextWriter` class? Or would you write tests only for those methods that you override, and those methods whose functionality might have changed as a side effect?

Comment: And would you retest the code if other functions or inherited classes call it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of opinions on what should be Unit Tested and what should not.
My personal belief is that for every function you write, you should have written a unit test first to specify the desired behavior. You then write your code to make this test pass. This is applicable for private, public, protected and internal. **If it is used it should be unit tested.**
Believe me this makes your life easier in the long run because if you or another developer changes existing unit tested code then a change in behavior is a lot more likely to be caught.

In the real world though it usually ends up being code first then test. However they should still be written for all access levels.